# SQL Query for getting the count and Rows with multiple record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out the SQL query for SQL Server for this:

TABLE:

```
ID    AppointmentID    TypeID
------------------------------
1     1992             1
2     1992             1
3     1992             2
4     1993             1
...
```

Desired result:

```
AppointmentID    TypeCount TypeID
---------------------------------
1992             2         1
```

I am only looking for the `AppointmentID` of `TypeID = 1` which got the count of more than 1.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3a3a/7)

The table we have:

```
CREATE TABLE appointments
(
    ID INT,
    AppointmentID INT,
    TypeID INT
);
```

Some data:

```
INSERT INTO appointments VALUES (1, 1992, 1);
INSERT INTO appointments VALUES (2, 1992, 1);
INSERT INTO appointments VALUES (3, 1992, 2);
INSERT INTO appointments VALUES (4, 1993, 1);
```

Query:

```
SELECT AppointmentID, count(*) AS TypeCount, TypeID FROM appointments
WHERE TypeID = 1
GROUP BY AppointmentID, TypeID
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS QUERY:

```
SELECT AppointmentID, COUNT(*) as TypeCount, TypeID FROM YourTableName 
WHERE TypeID =1 
GROUP BY AppointmentID, TypeID  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Replace YourTableName with actual table name